# Cannot install PHP 7.4 on Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: php, macos-mojave

I've tried more than once but i have the same error.
First i thought it was a connection problem but the problem is not there

```
brew install php@7.4
Warning: You are using macOS 10.14.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.

Warning: php@7.4 has been deprecated because it is a versioned formula!
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/apr/manifests/1.7.0_2
Already downloaded: /Users/fless/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/bea860ee12694d9b28c54323f66a2ed14e5b7b44c7fd2568ddd179b86f27829e--apr-1.7.0_2.bottle_manifest.json
...(some other lines of downloads)
/Users/fless/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b91f87090d445fea2ad28d6da786dbd810711f9458c1e61592b3bdbe8d872bf1--pcre2-10.39.tar.bz2
==> Downloading https://sqlite.org/2022/sqlite-autoconf-3370200.tar.gz
#############                                                             19.1%
curl: (18) transfer closed with 2411973 bytes remaining to read
Error: php@7.4: Failed to download resource "sqlite"
Download failed: https://sqlite.org/2022/sqlite-autoconf-3370200.tar.gz
```